# eachで作成したパラメーターをそれぞれの変数に代入する方法

Tags: ruby, sinatra

eachを使ってerb側で作成したパラメータ"car1", "car2", ...に対応する変数を、同じくeachを使ってRuby側で作成して代入したい場合には、どうすればよいでしょうか。
　最終的には、

```
varcar1 = params[:car1]
varcar2 = params[:car2]...
```

と続く形にしたいです。

```
(1..cars).each do |i|
  "varcar#{i} = params[:car#{i}]"
end
```

としてみたところ、変数varcarを作る段階ではエラーになりませんが、変数を使おうとするとエラーになります。

```
undefined method `join' for #<String:0x53925f0>
```

全体を文字列にしているところが問題なのだと思いますが、"#{i}"とすると作成段階のエラーになります。

```
 syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
 syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
 syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ']'
```

この場合、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。
　よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

個人的には先に配列 `varcar = []` を作って

```
varcar[1] = params[:car1]
varcar[2] = params[:car2]...
```

とすると思いますが、それはともかくとして。

## 前提条件1：スコープ

まず、（ `Enumerable#each` に続く）ブロック内で初めて出てきた（生成された）ローカル変数をブロック外で使うことは出来ません。ローカル変数のスコープがブロック内に限られるためです。

## 前提条件2：`Kernel#eval`

ブロック内に書かれた

```
"varcar#{i} = params[:car#{i}]"
```

では単なる文字列ですので、文字列として扱われるだけです。文字列の内容を実行するには `Kernel#eval` などのいわゆる eval 族を使う必要があります。つまり

```
(1..cars).each do |i|
  eval("varcar#{i} = params[:car#{i}]")
end
```

とすれば（ブロック内の）ローカル変数が生成できます。

## 本編：ご希望の内容の実現は不可能

前提条件2の `Kernel#eval` を用いてブロック内に `varcar1, varcar2` を作れたとしても、残念ながらそのローカル変数は前提条件1によりブロックのスコープを越えることが出来ません。
なお、以下の参考のところに記載されているように、インスタンス変数 `@varcar1, @varcar2` であれば `eval` を使ったり `instance_variable_set` メソッドを使ったりして作成できます。
参考：

- [Rubyで連番の変数を動的に作成 | EasyRamble](http://easyramble.com/ruby-dynamic-variables.html)
- [無題メモランダム: Rubyで変数を動的に取得/設定する方法](http://blog.mudaimemo.com/2009/12/ruby.html)
- [備忘録的なblog: rubyのリフレクション](http://se-bikou.blogspot.jp/2011/08/rubyeval.html)

また、

> ローカル変数はスクリプトコンパイル時に静的に決まるので、evalでローカル変数を設定することは出来ません。

（[Ruby 逆引きハンドブック](http://www.c-r.com/book/detail/705) るびきち著 p.653。なお、書籍としての対応バージョンは 1.9 までです）

という記載も見かけました。

## おまけ：`for` や `while` では？

`for` はブロックスコープを作らないので、内外の問題が生じない、とよく言われます（例えば [Rubyではfor whileなどで新たなスコープは生成されない - プログラマ憧れプログラマ日記](http://nobyu.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20090104/1231081726) ）。
ので私も `for` や `while` で解決できるのではないかと思ったのですが、残念ながらダメでした。

```
for i in [*1..3]
  eval("a#{i} = i; print a#{i}")  
end  
#=> 123

a1
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a1' for main:Object

i = 0
while i <= 3
  eval("a#{i} = i; print a#{i}")  
  i += 1  
end  
#=> 123

a1
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a1' for main:Object
```

ブロック内で `print` すれば出力できることから、ブロック内でローカル変数が生成出来ていることが分かります。
しかしブロック外でローカル変数を呼び出すと、 Ruby 1.9.3でも2.2.0でも NameError でした。つまり「そんな変数/メソッドは知らん」。スコープ外であることが分かります。